# Characteristic function and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

Let $\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}]$ be the **characteristic function**

If X is a continuous random variable, then:

$\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}] = \int e^{itx} f(x)dx$ (being $f(x)$ the probability density function of x)

If X is a discrete random variable, then:

$\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}] = \sum_{k} e^{itx_{k}} p(x_{k})$ (being $p(x)$ the probability mass function of x)

To be general Fourier transform can be define as (Ref: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/fourier-theorems/):

$F(s)=\frac{1}{A}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iBst}f(t)dt$

The choices that are found in practice are:

$A=\sqrt{2\pi}, B=\pm 1;$
$A=1, B=\pm 2\pi;$
$A=1, B=\pm 1$

Choosing A=1 and B=1 to relate it to the characteristic function, the inverse Fourier transform is:

$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ist}F(s)ds$

In continuous case:

$\phi_{x}(t) = \int e^{itx} f(x)dx \rightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixt}\phi_{x}(t)dt$

That is the utility of the characteristic function, it allows me to know the probability function

But in the discrete case I get problems:

If discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is :

$F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-2\pi sn/N}f(n)$

The inverse DFT is:

$f(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{2\pi sn/N}F(s)$

So, Would the "inverse" characteristic function be

$\phi_{x}(t) = \sum_{k} e^{itx_{k}} p(x_{k}) \rightarrow P(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi N}\sum_{k} e^{-ixt_{k}}\phi_{x}(t_{n})$ ?

So if FT can have different definitions for the continuous case. What happen with the discrete case? How many definitions are?

Comment: By using the distribution function, the discrete and continuous (as well as mixed) can be combined (Stieltjes integral) as $f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{itx}dF(x)$ while $F(b)-F(a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ e^{-itb}- e^{-ita}}{-it}f(t)dt$.

Comment: But if $F_{x}(x)=P(X\leq x) = \sum_{x_{i} \leq x} P(X=x_{i}) = \sum_{x_{i} \leq x} p(x_{i})$ How do you integrate it and put inside the integral?

Comment: Stieltjes integral - F(x) consists of constants plus jumps  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral.